# How to read data using POST method instead of GET in Postman?

Tags: post, get, postman, web-api-testing, http-method

I've been told to use POST method to read data instead of the GET method. The tool I'm using is Postman. How can I use POST to fetch data/resources from the server?? I'm testing using any of the testing websites like reqres, gorest, etc.

Tried nothing as of now

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear but if this api you use exposes a POST method to read data, that means that simply instead of sending a GET request to said URL, you should send a POST http request and the response will be the data you fetched.

On the contrary, if you are composing this api yourself and asking here how to do it, you could simply create a meathod for fetching data and expose this method to a POST request.

Comment: I'm not composing the api myself. I'm just doing testing where I've been told that how can you fetch/retrieve data from the server using POST instead of GET in Postman tool in a general sense. Consider something like i'm undergoing some sort of training where I've told to research this.

Comment: Than you should simply send a POST request instead where you would send a GET one.

Comment: can you tell me how? i'm an absolute beginner when it comes to this. I did send a POST and in response it is showing as data created instead of retrieving me data that i actually wanted. And you do get that I want to access data using POST and not create!!

Comment: Either show what you've tried, what the api exposes and more details or search a tutorial for this stuff man.
fyi questions on stackoverflow shouldn't be a discussion and you should provide details on your problem and do research prior to posting a question. https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/

Comment: so this is the url on which i'm sending a GET request to access data - https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 .......... lets say the data i'm getting in response is somewhat like this (id - 1, name - john, job - QA ; id - 2, name - sam, job - Web Dev)........  Now i want to access the same data (id - 1, name - john, job - QA ; id - 2, name - sam, job - Web Dev) using the POST method on this url. How can I do that in Postman?? I hope you get what i'm saying

Comment: If you checked out the link, you can see next to the url in postman the request type and change it to POST, from what I see it doesn't seem like this api exposes this same respons in POST so there is no point in doing what you suggest..

Comment: The dropdown before the URL in postman contains different HTTP verbs. By default it is GET but you can change it to POST/PUT/DELETE etc

Comment: I have a URL on which I am sending a GET request to access data - https://sampledataapi.com/API/index.php/alluser , Now i cant access the same url with POST. The dropdown before the URL in postman contains different HTTP verbs. By default it is GET but you can change it to POST/PUT/DELETE etc.